# Designing a controller (control systems)

Tags: homework, controller

I have to propose a controller C such that the entire closed loop system would be stable and the error approaches zero as time goes to infinite. I'll now explain in more detail.

I need to find a controller C such that the sensitivity transfer function:

[image]

would be stable and there would not be any unstable zero/poles cancellations in the product PC.

Moreover, the following transfer function:

[image]

has to yield an output that approaches zero as time goes to infinity (by final value theorem) for a parabolic input (whose Laplace transform is 2/s^3).

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: What course is this for?  It should all be in the book, or the lecture notes.  What have you attempted, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It's for a control system course and I have tried a controller which has a pole of three degree at 0 and (s+13)(s+5) in the numerator  to simplify things, I've done that in some variations and in all of them I got stuck. I've tried to apply a Routh-Hurwitz criterion for a three/four degree polynomial I've managed to get to in the denominator (with parametric coefficients as well  and faced contradictions.  It looks impossible to me..

Comment: Hi, please click the [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/597125/edit) link below the question and add this information.  That is so the next person to read this question doesn't have to read the comments also.  We can help, but you must show your work.